# MVC3 webhosting common resources for under $5/month

Tags: web-hosting, looking-for-hosting, asp.net-mvc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find web hosting that meets my requirements?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements)

I am looking for a very cheap under $5/month MVC3 hosting. I found some offers which seem too good to be true, and others more expensive. Could you please recommend me a company that you like? I found other posts on the internet but nothing very current and I know I can trust this place.

Answer (score 0):

You can find many hosting provider nowadays with affordable cost. Just by googling it, you can find your provider. If your budget is limited, you can consider asphostportal.com. My friend recommend me to go with them. He has hosted his site for many years.